# is there a shortened "if then" syntax available in Lua?

Tags: lua

Is there a shorted "if / then" syntax available in Lua (I'm using Corona SDK specifically), like in some other languages... In particular along the lines of:

```
 res = (a == b) ? "It worked" : "It did NOT work"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To represent `x = a ? b : c`, the [lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TernaryOperator) suggests:

> A frequently used and highly recommend solution is to combine the `and`
> and `or` binary operators in a way that closely approximates the ternary
> operator:
>
> ```
> x = a and b or c
> ```

To represent `x = a ? b : c ? d : e`, the wiki further suggests:

> ```
> x = a and b or c and d or e
> ```

**WARNING:** This technique may fail if `b` or `d` are ever `nil` or `false`.

Comment: While this is the right answer, the custom at SO is still to summarize a link's content to protect against future link rot.

Answer (score 8):

the common idiom is  to use and/or construction, since boolean expressions are short-circuited in Lua.

```
res  = a == b and "It worked" or "It did NOT work"
```

Though personally I prefer if/then/else almost in all cases.

Comment: Note this limitation, though: `a == b and nil or 42` will always evaluate to `42`, even when `a == b` is true. You can only use this technique when you can rely on the result in the "iftrue" arm being neither `nil` nor `false`.

Answer (score -2):

lua dont have the shortway,only this

```
 a=a or "hi"
```

just same like:

```
 if not(a) then  a="hi" end
```